# Best way of creating a IEnumerable<MyObj> from csv file input?

Tags: c#, csv

I've got some large csv files that I need to import into IEnumerable (prob a list) so that I can do some "magic" on them before saving into a db.  I don't need every value (column) from the csv.

However, I can't find a better alternative than this:

```
Read csv file by line
Split the line on ,
new MyObj{
  Prop1 = split[0],
  Prop2 = split[1],
  Prop3 = split[6],
  Prop4 = split[7],
  Prop5 = split[9]
}
Add new MyObj to List
```

This works and is quick enough, but seems very clunky?

Is there an alternative (other than add a ctor, which acheives the same as above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSV parser - there is one in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.aspx) namespace - the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

[FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) is another popular option, and there are many free ones around (just search).

Answer (score 0):

You may find the the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine as long as you are sure that there will never be a comma in the data.

There are many csv readers around on the net that are more robust: [here's one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar application that performs the same form of translation, we read all the lines into an IDictionary and then perform the new object creation using Data Parallelism Parallel.ForEach(sourceCollection, item => Process(key, item)). Any errors we log the Key which is the row number.

Comment: How well does this perform?  have you compared to just the plain ole way?

Comment: On our Prod servers, dual Quad core it works great easily 3x times faster than standard ForEach loop, on virtual environments it's performance is improved over single thread model but not by a high margin. I have tested it compared with the VB TextFieldParser and it our case it was faster due to logic requirements.